# Creating a POST body in VBA

Tags: vba

Does anyone know how to construct a POST DATA body in VBA?  I'm trying to upload rather lengthy strings via a post call using the "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" object.  I'm not tied to using that object for making the HTTP request either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
Dim XMLHttp As Object: Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
XMLHttp.Open "POST", "http://www.lfkfklkf.com", False
XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
XMLHttp.send "q=ploppy&x=cake"
Debug.print XMLHttp.responseText
Set XMLHttp = Nothing
```