# Upload a file with POST (multipart/form-data) using VBA

Tags: vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a POST body in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773673/creating-a-post-body-in-vba)

Does anyone know if it's possible to upload a file via POST body (multipart/form-data) using VBA?  I'm currently using the Microsoft.XMLHTTP object, but I'm not tied to it if that doesn't support multipart POST.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
Set oHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
oHttp.Open "POST", theUrl, False
oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHttp.Send "body=thebody"
```

Comment: You want to upload *one file* as multipart? Why? (And BTW your code sample shows `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.)

Comment: It's a REST call I have to conform to.  It can either be one file, or multiple files...