# How to send a post request via excel to a RESTful Web Service without using XML?

Tags: web-services, vba, rest, excel, excel-2007

Here's the deal: I had a excel table that fulfills a MySQL table. I already made a procedure in server side who receives the sheet, read it and put it on the database. Saddly the sheet and data table doesn't have the same structure, so I need to use a php object/script in server side to manipulate it. I have a interface to upload the file (excel file), so the PHP program can read it...

...but my boss job isn't make my life easier, is it? NO! He says that is a lot of work have to upload every excel file by the web interface. So, he asked me to make a button in the sheet that he might click after his "job" is done. That would replace the web interface. 
But, the system itself is a interface that would be saled one day (well, it's the plan!). So, I just can't just role out the web interface.

WHAT I'M ASKING IS: There's a way that I could send a file (the sheet itself) in a post method straight from the VBA Macro without using XML files and name each data that I'm sending, like a form post?

So far, I've found some tutorials or even some SO posts that made me get somewhere. But all of them were talking about a XML, and I already have a method that receives a HTTP POST (from a form) and work. I aiming to reuse the same method. From my VBA script I'm already able to make the request (not a big deal) and post it. But, in the server-side script, I'm expecting a POST come out from a form, so it calls a field's name. I don't seen to be able to do that from a VBA post. =/

Comment: You can use an XMLHttp object to POST data to a web server. Despite its name it does not require that you post the data in XML format...  Short example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773673/creating-a-post-body-in-vba

Comment: In that example, you will pass the data through URL or am I wrong?

Comment: Post method doesn't pass data via the URL - it goes in the request body.  GET uses the URL to pass data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the [answer](http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/)... the two first functions/methods define how to send a file to a web service. You only need the file path and the URL from service. It has answered even more than I expected. :D